# AWS permissions for Fargate and SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-fargate, ssm

I'm trying to create some infrastructure for a service I am building on AWS using AWS Fargate.  I'm using SSM as a value store for some of my application configuration, so I need both the regular permissions for Fargate as well as additional permissions for SSM.  However, after banging my head against this particular wall for a while, I've come to the conclusion that I just don't understand AWS IAM in general or this problem in particular, so I'm here for help.

The basis of my IAM code comes from [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@bradford_hamilton/deploying-containers-on-amazons-ecs-using-fargate-and-terraform-part-2-2e6f6a3a957f); the IAM code is actually not in that tutorial but rather in [this file](https://github.com/bradford-hamilton/terraform-ecs-fargate/blob/master/terraform/roles.tf) in the github repo linked to that tutorial.  I presume I need to retain that STS permission for something although I'm not entirely sure what.

I've converted the IAM code from the tutorial into a JSON document because I find JSON easier to work with than the Terraform native thing.  Here's what I've come up with.  It doesn't work.  I would like to know why it doesn't work and how to fix it.  Please ELI5 (explain like I'm 5 years old) because I know nothing about this.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ssm:GetParameters",
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "sts:AssumeRole"
      ],
      "Principal": {
        "Service": ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a minimum, your ECS task should have below permissions:

1. Ability to assume a role
2. Resource level permissions

In the [example](https://github.com/bradford-hamilton/terraform-ecs-fargate/blob/master/terraform/roles.tf), you have referred, An IAM Role is created with the following:

- A trust relationship is attached. <-- To enable ECS task to assume an IAM role
- AWS managed policy `AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy` is attached. <-- Resource permissions

So, in order to retrieve the SSM parameter values, add below resource permissions.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ssm:Describe*",
            "ssm:Get*",
            "ssm:List*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/{your-path-hierarchy-to-parameter}/*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If your Secrets uses KMS, then grant necessary kms permissions (`kms:Decrypt`). Refer [specifying-sensitive-data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide///specifying-sensitive-data.html) for reference.

Comment: The trick to this was that I had to add those permissions as a Task Role, not as a Task Execution Role.